# OP changed their question and now there is an answer targeting the new version and another answer targeting the old version

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

OP asked a question. Someone posted an answer targeting this question. OP changed their question entirely (which they shouldn't have done). Someone else posted an answer targeting the new question.

There are two options:

1. Rolling back
2. Not rolling back

Option 1 invalidates the new answer. Option 2 invalidates the old answer. What should be done?

Comment: The first answer wasn't a non-answer, right?

Comment: I can see this going both ways. You'd have to give more details for determine which way is the best. (For instance, if as Jamal suggests, the first answer is a non-answer, then there is nothing lost by losing that answer.)

Comment: @Louis both answers answer the respective questions.

Comment: OP shouldn't edit to ask a new question, they should create a new question and rollback the old one. I don't know if I would rollback for them though, but if I did I'd leave a comment linking to how SE works.

Answer (score 1):

Since both answers are legitimate, the question can still be rolled back, if the edit appears to ask a follow-up question. The OP can then post that as a new question and the second answerer could provide the same answer to that question.

Be sure to also mention this as a comment so that it's not done again.  Answer invalidations can happen with edits from new users, and it could cause confusion.